# Is it possible to update a Blazor Component file .Razor and not have to reload the app?

Tags: wpf, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am writing a WPF app that will be like a wireframe tool that generates and edits .razor pages for a Blazor Serverside Website.

The issue I run into is that whenever my WPF desktop app writes directly to a component page file (.razor), or creates a new page it requires the Blazor App to be stopped and restarted to view the newly created content.

Is there a way to change a source .razor file where I don't have to restart the Blazor App to see the changes?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it at development time.

Use 'dotnet watch' on the Blazor server-side project while you are editing it with your wireframe tool. Make sure to read over the [.NET Hot Reload support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/hot-reload?view=aspnetcore-6.0) article and the related [Support Code Changes document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/supported-code-changes-csharp?view=vs-2022) so that you know what to expect.

Personally, I have found 'dotnet watch' to be somewhat finicky for certain projects and certain dev workflows, but it can feel like magic when its working.

If you are looking for a way to dynamically modify a deployed application, then 'dotnet watch' wouldn't be appropriate. I am unaware of a safe way to dynamically recompile and integrate .razor files in a deployed (production) web application.

There does appear to be [a way to turn on dynamic recompilation of .cshtml Razor files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#enable-runtime-compilation-for-all-environments). I'm not sure if that will affect .razor Blazor files or not, but you could give it a try.